# Fine script location and change directory into it

Tags: shell, unix

I want to find a script "A.sh", in $WORKSPACE directory on jenkins. There are multiple subdirectories in $WORKSPACE.

Post I find the script, i'd like to get inside that directory and execute the script.

What is the most efficient way to execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Post I find the script, **i'd like to** get inside that directory and
>   **execute the script**.

This is a typical application of command substitution in `shell`.

Suppose that there is only one `A.sh`, write the below lines to a file, say, 
`executeA.sh`

```
workspace=$WORKSPACE
$(find "$workspace" -type f -name "A.sh")
```

Now comes the important part, just [[ **source** ]](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html) the above script in the current shell

```
. executeA.sh
```

You're good to go <kbd>:-)</kbd>

---

**How this works?**

- Find command just prints each output to the `stdout` in the normal case
- If the put the `find` inside command substitution, the result that is the full path to the filename itself is treated as a command

Comment: You could be good to go without sourcing as well, since find will return an absolute path (if the script is executable). In many cases sourcing and executing may produce quite different results, but I understand what you are saying.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin One reason, I went ahead with sourcing is because the op is playing with some environment variables like `$WORKSPACE` which affects the way `jenkins` work and shouldn't be accidentally modified. The source file provides a neat interface for having copies of these variables.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too. It was unclear to me exactly what was his intent. I think your answer is likely the one he is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This worked better for me:

```
locate -br '^A.sh$'
```

However, I wish to use variables instead of A.sh as hard coded. Any best practices to do that?

Comment: You could do it this way. `var=nameofscript";locate -br '^'"$var"'$'`. The idea is that you need to put the variables inside the double quotes for them to expand to their respective values. But still you need the other regex parts which you put in single quotes.

Comment: Yes, that worked smooth....I am trying to now store the vairable and cd into it. Is it possible in a single atomic command